# how do you call a person who doesn't share responsibility

Tags: vocabulary

How do you call a person who does all the work on their own for a given project and never share responsibilities with other people just because they think that no-one else could ever be as good as themselves?

This word has a negative connotation and is not a compliment.

Comment: How do I call them? Very well thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest ***Poor delegator*** or ***anti-delegator*** or perhaps simply ***control-freak***.

There's an article [here](https://www.bbc.com/worklife/article/20150401-why-you-find-it-hard-to-delegate) about the phenomenon including this:

> She was convinced nobody else in the company could do it exactly right
>   — so she just did it herself. She could do it better anyway, she
>   thought.
>
> Sound familiar? Then you might be an **anti-delegator**.  Even if you
>   aren’t, you likely know someone who is. (...)
>   Being a **poor delegator** can also affect you mentally, demotivate your team and hold up work for everyone else, said Lunsford.

A [control freak](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/control-freak?s=t) is more informal and the most negative. From Dictionary:

> a person having a strong need for control over people or situations.

Answer (score 1):

In sports this person would be a [**ball hog**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_hog). Someone who doesn't pass to other players because they want the glory for themselves or believe they're the most talented.

Overall, not a team player.

The analogy would be immediately recognizable in other contexts.

See also [**glory hog**](https://slangdefine.org/g/glory-hog-4e2e.html) and **show-off**.  Neither of them is a great fit, but carry many of the same characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Though not specific to "not delegating responsibility" -- such a person is mostly likely an "elitist".

Since "doing the work" is almost universally considered a virtue, I don't think you'll find a simple phrase to turn it into a negative.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of turning virtues into negatives. Ask any kid who was beat up on the playground for being a *nerd*.

Answer (score 0):

An independent worker.
If someone is independent, they may:

Prefer projects where they can work alone, rather than in a group.
Become known as the person to take on a project and run with it.
Default to “just getting it done myself,” rather than looping others in.
Tend to sit alone, or look for “escapes” where they can get away and focus.
Source:
https://www.hiresuccess.com/help/team-player-vs-works-independently-personality-types-at-work

Comment: Good answer on its own. But, the OP wants a negative connotation. Independent worker sounds like praise on a job evaluation.  Your link has a better contrast. *Not a team-player* is better.